# laravel pluck selected edit view

Tags: laravel-5.4

how to make edit in view display as i selected to edit.

it's my controller:

```php
public function edit($id_mr){
    $medical_records = Medical_record::findOrFail($id_mr);
    return view('nurul_nabawi.medical_record.edit', compact('medical_records'));
}
```

it's my edit.blade.php

```html
<div>
    <label>Nama Pasien</label>                                          
    {!! Form::select('id_pasien', \App\Patient::pluck('nama_pasien'), NULL, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: You can't access `\App\Patient::pluck('nama_pasien')` – it's not an instance, only class. `Pluck` receives values for key from object/collection. If you defined valid relation to patient try `$medical_records->patient->pluck('nama_pasien')`.

Comment: how to display the 'nama_pasien' that we selected before?